# Regex on Unicode string is interpreted as intended by the debugger but not by the program

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8

This is - reduced to a minimum - a program I am using to read and interpret some UTF8 text files:

```
use 5.012;
use utf8;
binmode STDIN, ':utf8';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ /BOLETIM DE ANÁLISE N/) {print "Boletim\n";}
    if ($_ =~ /DADOS REFERENTES A AMOSTRA/) {print "Dados\n";}
}
```

The input file contains lines that should satisfy both the regexes, and I verified with TextWrangler that the file is indeed in UTF-8, with Unix endlines. However, the program recognizes only the second one, that do not contain accented characters.

What is weird (to me, at least) is that when I am in the debugger and run the same line

```
    x if ($_ =~ /BOLETIM DE ANÁLISE N/) {print "Boletim\n";}
```

when $_ is the string `'BOLETIM DE ANÁLISE N° 274734/2011-0  '`, the regex fires and "Boletim" is printed.

Why should the debugger and the program have different behaviours?

Many thanks in advance

Adriano

PS I am on Mac Os X 10.7.5 and Perl v5.12.4.

Comment: Check whether it is the non-ASCII character that is causing the problem by using a pattern of `/BOLETIM DE AN(.)LISE N/`. Then, if it matches, check the value of `ord $1` and compare it with `ord 'Á'`.

Comment: Borodin, actually /AN(.)LISE/ does not match but AN(.*)LISE does. ord($1) is then 195 and ord(Á) is 193. Mistery partially solved: characters should have been mangled in some cut&paste... but why the regex works in the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't decoding your UTF-8 files properly.

The Unicode value for *capital-A-acute* is `193` or `0xC1`. Your results with matching `AN(.*)LISE` show that you have a multi-byte representation for this character, starting with `195`. The UTF-8 encoding for this character is `C3 81` (or `195 129` in decimal) so you are looking at two one-byte characters instead of the single byte `C1`.

You can confirm this by writing

```
print join ' ', map sprintf('%02X', ord), split //, $1;
```

after the match operation. You will get `C3 81`.

You set `STDIN` and `STDOUT` to use the `utf8` layer using `binmode`, but the `<>` operator reads from the `ARGV` file handle unless `@ARGV` is empty.

I suggest you write

```
binmode ARGV, ':utf8';
```

to also decode data read from `ARGV`. Then all should be well.